# A movie about a bank robbery?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this movie at least 12 years ago.

It involves a guy sending letters to his criminal associates detailing a planned robbery. After he has posted them, he gets arrested.

Then the associates turn up and wonder where he is but decide to continue with the plan he has outlined.

While they are carrying out the robbery etc. the original guy escapes from the prison and tries to get home.

Other details I remember

- All the associates had exactly the same bag
- The police cars had small explosives placed in their engines to prevent them from being able to go anywhere
- At the end, the robbery has taken place and the associates go back to the guys house to split up the money, as they are driving off, the original guy manages to crawl up the hill to his house.

Any ideas? It's not a fantastic movie at all, but I can't remember what it was called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It came out 23 years ago, but I think you're talking about [*Disorganized Crime*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disorganized_Crime).  You included a few extra details that I don't remember (the matching bags and exploding engines), but the plot summary is the same:

> The story begins in a small town in western Montana where New Jersey based bank robber Frank Salazar has been hiding out from the law after a series of bank robberies in Newark. Upon realizing that the local bank contains a large amount of cash, Salazar recruits four former accomplices to come to town and help him rob the bank. Among them are Nick Bartkowski, a nervous and possibly alcoholic safecracker; Max Green, an old school explosives expert with a heart condition; Ray Forgy, a young, wisecracking auto thief and getaway driver; and Carlos Barrios, a well-manicured lookout and weapons expert.
>
> Before they can arrive, however, two New Jersey detectives (George Denver and Bill Lonigan) catch up with Salazar, arrest him, and extradite him back to New Jersey. But Salazar soon escapes and becomes hopelessly lost in the Montana wilderness as he flees Denver and Lonigan's custody.
>
> Unaware of Salazar's arrest and escape, the four accomplices arrive and realize that he is nowhere to be found. They finally decide to take down the bank on their own but must go through several humorous ordeals before they can complete their plan.

Despite the (at the time) all-star cast, I'm inclined to agree that it's not that fantastic.  They were going for the same kind of heist film/comedy as *Ocean's 11*, but they didn't quite pull it off.